# Как увидеть границы(контур) метки при наведении?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Подскажите как увидеть границы(контур) метки при наведении чтобы можно было ей вписать правильные координаты?

Сейчас метка смещена вниз. А то по одной метке исправлять явно неправильно, наверняка есть способ увидеть границы метки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]?

```js
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.7, 37.6],
        zoom: 10,
        controls: []
    });
    
    var polygonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div class="pin"><div class="pulse"></div><div class="detailed-product"></div></div>');

    var polygonPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
        [55.662693, 37.558416], {
            hintContent: 'HTML метка сложной формы',
            balloonContentHeader : '<a href = "#">Название заголовка</a>',
        }, {
            iconLayout: polygonLayout,
            iconShape: {   
                type: 'Polygon',
                coordinates: [
                    [[-28,-76],[28,-76],[28,-20],[12,-20],[0,-4],[-12,-20],[-28,-20]]
                ]
            }
        }
    );
    map.geoObjects.add(polygonPlacemark);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU&amp;apikey=<ваш API-ключ>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        *, ::after, ::before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .pin{
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
            position: absolute;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
                  transform: rotate(-45deg);
            left: 50%;
            top: 81%;
            margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
            border: 5px solid  #c20430;
            -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
                  animation-name: bounce;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
                  animation-fill-mode: both;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
                  animation-duration: 1s;
        }
        
        .pin:after {
            content: '';
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
            margin: 4px;
            background: black;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
        
        .pulse{
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            border-radius: 50%;
            height: 14px;
            width: 14px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 7%;
            top: 37%;
            margin: 11px 0px 0px -12px;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) rotateX(55deg);
                  transform: rotate(45deg) rotateX(55deg);
        }
        .pulse:after {
          content: "";
          border-radius: 50%;
          height: 40px;
          width: 40px;
          position: absolute;
          margin: -13px 0 0 -13px;
          -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
                  animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
          -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          opacity: 0.0;
          box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px #c20430;
          -webkit-animation-delay: 1.1s;
                  animation-delay: 1.1s
        }
        
        @-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
          0% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
                    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
            opacity: 0.0;
          }
          50% {
            opacity: 1.0;
          }
          100% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
                    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
            opacity: 0;
          }
        }
        
        @keyframes pulsate {
          0% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
                    transform: scale(0.1, 0.1);
            opacity: 0.0;
          }
          50% {
            opacity: 1.0;
          }
          100% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
                    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
            opacity: 0;
          }
        }
        
        @-webkit-keyframes bounce {
          0% {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg);
                    transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg)
          }
          60% {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
                    transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg)
          }
          80% {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
                    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg)
          }
          100% {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
                    transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg)
          }
        }
        
        @keyframes bounce {
          0% {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg);
                    transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg)
          }
          60% {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
                    transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg)
          }
          80% {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg);
                    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg)
          }
          100% {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
                    transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg)
          }
        }
        
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: подобные маркеры обычно просто смещают на половину ширины влево, и на 100% высоты вверх. с условным квадратным маркером 32х32 в `.pin` ставится `left: -16px; top: -32px` и все попадает куда надо.

Comment: понятно @teran, спасибо за ответ. Если посмотреть в примере: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape/ видно что Polygon идеально обведён, контур попадает точка в точку. Наверняка есть ещё какой то способ высчитать как правильно строить контур? Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: мне вообще не ясно, зачем вы координаты полигона этого квадрата со стрелкой из яндекс примера прицепили к своему почти круглому маркеру. Сделайте там shape: 'Circle' нужного радиуса со сдвигом центра вверх, да и все.

Comment: Понял @teran, спасибо за ответ!